# Pergunta ampla ou simplesmente não foi devidamente compreendida?

Tags: debate

Não tenho participado ativamente da comunidade a algum tempo, mas semana passada precisei fazer uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/359868/como-evitar-acesso-ao-banco-de-dados). Não estou reclamando que a pergunta foi "fechada", pois ela obteve uma resposta antes e essa resposta respondeu minha dúvida.

Ou seja, alguém que quis entender e ajudar, não achou que a pergunta estava ampla e respondeu. Talvez os membros da comunidade estão muito legaglista e esqueceram o objetivo da comunidade?

Com "Objetivo da comunidade" quero dizer o seguinte: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Ao meu ver, minha pergunta abrange ao menos dois pontos da lista que são:

- ferramentas comuns entre programadores

  > Já pensei em talvez criar uma interface entre o banco de dados e as pessoas que acessam essas informações, mas não sei se essa é uma solução viável e que talvez houvesse outros métodos ou ferramentas para fazer isso. (esse é o motivo da pergunta)
- dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software

  > Quais os melhores meios de proteger os dados do banco de dados, sendo que várias pessoas tem acesso ao banco,

Comment: Seria legal [edit] e descrever o que entende por "Objetivo da comunidade". Provavelmente ajudaria na condução da conversa. Isso que você pediu na sua pergunta eu já devo ter resolvido de umas 20 maneiras diferentes em situações diferentes, deveria então postar todas? (uma delas, por exemplo, é deixar a pessoa fazer só insert. outra delas é cada um acessar o DB com a sua própria senha, outra delas foi fazer um "filtro" entre o cliente e o servidor, que intermedia o MySQL. tem muitas maneiras e umas são boas em alguns casos e inviáveis em outros). No meu ver, faltam elementos essenciais no post.

Comment: Ah, e a resposta dada não serviria pra praticamente nenhum dos casos que eu já esbarrei. PS: Nem aqui nem lá dei votos, nem positivo nem negativo (Aqui talvez eu vote em futuras respostas, dependendo do teor). Estou apenas tentando contribuir com o assunto.

Comment: Exatamente, esse é o meu ponto. A resposta dada parece ser a solução ideal pro meu problema original, e talvez se o AR demorasse um pouco mais pra responder talvez eu estaria até agora pesquisando possíveis soluções, sem saber exatamente oq procurar...

Comment: É nessa hora que descrever melhor seu cenário pode reduzir a "amplitude" da coisa, tipo comentar o que tentou e pq não deu certo, e/ou as formas que tentou fazer e onde imaginou que teria problemas, requisitos, detalhes do cenário em questão. A dúvida é pertinente, mas o "ampla" é justamente isso. Não se questionou escopo, qualidade, apenas a amplitude. E geralmente voto por amplitude significa que alguém parou para analisar seu problema antes de votar, para poder chegar nessa conclusão.

Comment: @KaduAmaral vc poderia limitar mais sua questão nas abordagens.

Comment: Ninguém sabe seu problema original a não ser você. O objetivo da comunidade é apresentar soluções que ajudem várias pessoas aprenderem sobre programação. Quando só a pessoa que perguntou sabe o que está falando, só ela tem as informações necessárias para avaliar se aquilo é bom ou ruim, então ela não está contribuindo com a comunidade, está só resolvendo o seu problema. E nem sabemos se realmente resolve, há histórico de algumas pessoas aceitarem qualquer coisa que lhe grade. Um dos objetivos da comunidade é poder avaliar se o conteúdo é bom. Se só uma pessoa tem subsídios para isto...

Comment: ... algo está errado. A pergunta aqui está discutindo se a pergunta está no escopo ou não, e lá ela foi fechada como ampla. Poderia ser ser fechada como não clara, eu preferi ampla porque até dá para entender oque quer, mas com poucas informações diversas respostas podem ser certas, e ninguém a não ser o AP pode saber qual delas responde. Na verdade até o AP pode achar que respondeu e ter coisa melhor ou mais correta, se alguém puder saber exatamente o que seria, conforme foi orientado na pergunta poderia ter coisa melhor e mais correta.

Comment: Então a discussão aqui sequer faz sentido. Agora até o AP mostra aqui não tem certeza se a resposta realmente é boa. Particularmente considero aquela resposta ruim e potencialmente danosa para outras pessoas aprenderem.

Comment: Só acho triste que há uma crítica a mim depois de eu ter respondido mais de 5000 perguntas, ter dado mais de 20 mil votos, ter participado em milhares de análise em filas e muitas ações fora, e de ter comentado tantas outras milhares de vezes para as pessoas, e tendo feito uma imensidão de ações de ações de moderação, de estar aqui o dia todo quase todos os dias por mais de 5 anos, tudo isso sem receber uma centavo, e ser considerado preguiçoso.

Comment: Maniero falou basicamente tudo o que eu pretendia responder aqui, então só completando, acho que a discussão partiu de muitas premissas erradas. Uma pessoa entender a pergunta não é justificativa para ela se manter aberta. Se assim fosse dificilmente teríamos uma pergunta fechada - a probabilidade deve ser que existe pelo menos uma pessoa que entende cada uma das perguntas, por pior que seja. Outra que a pergunta foi fechada como ampla, não como fora do escopo, como já comentado, então indagações nessa pergunta não fizeram muito sentido. Mas, enfim...

Comment: ... eu votei como ampla por alguns motivos principais: a pergunta resume-se a apresentação de um problema que não foi completamente descrito. Ao meu ver, e é o que justifica o meu voto, quando uma pergunta possui as perguntas chaves "quais os melhores", que foi o caso, ou "qual é mais rápido", etc, precisa haver também uma lista de requisitos que deverão ser avaliados como critério de qual é melhor. A forma que eu julgo ser melhor, ou ainda, aquela que é melhor para mim pois atende **os meus requisitos** pode não ser melhor para você. Sem os requisitos descritos, a pergunta demandaria...

Comment: ... cada um responder a solução que julga ser melhor com os requisitos que ele levantou ali na hora. O resultado disso provavelmente seria um apanhado de respostas que, com sorte, uma responderia o que você desejava ler. Pior que isso, seriam respostas impossíveis de serem avaliadas pela comunidade, pois como não conhecemos os seus requisitos, não temos como saber qual atenderia da melhor forma. Somente você iria conseguir decidir isso, mas perde-se o interesse da pergunta perante todo o resto da comunidade.

Comment: O outro ponto é justamente o fato que se uma pessoa entendeu não garante que ela responderá da forma correta ou que responderá a melhor solução de fato. Basicamente o fato de ter sido fechada como ampla não significa que não possa ser respondida, que não para entender ou que ficaram com preguiça de responder, mas sim que o estado em que ela se encontrava poderia trazer muito mais problemas que soluções, então é comum fecharem de forma a prevenir o surgimento de uma bola de neve.

Comment: Pra mim o problema está muito bem descrito na pergunta "Tem várias pessoas acessando o banco de produção e preciso proteger alguns dados extremamente sigilosos", a resposta sobre "Data Warehouse" é a melhor que vi, se vc acha que teria outras resposta melhores, pra mim isso é só mais um motivo pra não ter fechado a pergunta. 

Não fiz nenhuma crítica pessoal a você @Maniero, até pq vc comentou na pergunta pra complementar e eu tentei faze-lo descrevendo melhor o cenário. Peço desculpas se vc se sentiu ofendido.

Comment: Então é só votar para reabrir e deixar a comunidade decidir por si só.

Comment: Eu não disse que teria respostas melhores, só poderia ter piores, porque a pergunta é ampla e não clara. Quem entende do assunto sabe que deixa aberta há muitas interpretações e escrever genericamente é bastante prejudicial. Foi pedido para dizer exatamente o que queria, dar mais contexto a pergunta e isto não foi feito, a pergunta continua aberta a interpretações e suposições do que é o contexto.

Comment: Editei o titulo da pergunta, uma vez que somos todos adultos aqui, não precisamos nos rebaixar a esse tipo de insulto bobo como dizer que quem fecha ou analisa pergunta tem preguiça. Não é esse o **objetivo** da comunidade, podemos questionar e discutir sem se fazer uso desse tipo de termo pejorativo.

Comment: Ao meu ver a pergunta é ampla e faltou um pouco de pesquisa para criá-la, nós estamos dispostos a ajudar e não acho justo presumir "preguiça", as vezes falta você compreender que algumas informações, que só você sabe, sobre seu problema são essenciais para solução dele e essas devem ser transparantes para quem vai te auxiliar.

Answer (score 4):

## Só um comentário longo

Eu entendo que você possa ter se frustrado um pouco por ter sua pergunta fechada ou negativada, na verdade isso é o máximo que pode acontecer. No entanto, entenda que sua pergunta é muito ampla e isso pode trazer respostas que apontam soluções ruins (não estou a falar daquela resposta) e ter uma pergunta fechada não é ruim assim, há sempre a opção de *perguntar* novamente ou *editar*. Além disso, claro que podem surgir outras respostas boas, mas quem irá garantir? Seria mais fácil aparecer coisas que não vão servir nem para você e nem para outra pessoa que esta a visitar o site e tudo isso depende de como alguém vai interpretar sua pergunta, e o fechamento é para prevenir isto.

Se eu estivesse no seu lugar eu tentaria limitar bem o escopo do problema e fornecer o máximo de contexto possível, pense na pessoa que vai responder e **tente se colocar no lugar dela**. É uma dica ;)

Falta muita informação na pergunta: o ambiente é uma empresa pelo que parece, não sabemos como funciona a hierarquia da empresa ou que tipo de funcionário ela tem e quais serão os perfis de acesso ao banco de dados, sem dúvidas é mais complicado do que aparenta ser.

Então, de uma revisada na pergunta para ver se consegue deixa-la mais canônica possível.

Comment: Justamente pelo contexto ser empresarial eu tenho que tomar bastante cuidado pra não acabar falando demais. Não sei, talvez eu seja burro e não saiba me expressar corretamente, pois não vejo nenhuma amplitude na pergunta. Já editei a pergunta e deixei bem claro no título o problema, descrevi o problema e contexto no corpo da pergunta e deixei a pergunta bem específica no final "proteger dados sensíveis" e "busca de informações para gerar métricas", resposta obtida "Data Warehouse". Não sei como seria mais claro que isso, talvez postar um diagrama relacional do banco junto com usuário e senha..

Comment: @KaduAmaral Data Warehouse já é um tema amplo se não tiver um ponto especifico, e isso deixa sua pergunta ampla, se vai usar Data Warehouse para resolver isso seria melhor fazer a pergunta mais focada nisto então ao invés de pedir sugestões o que deixa uma margem de amplitude grande na pergunta. Deixei um [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/359868/como-evitar-acesso-ao-banco-de-dados#comment720378_359868) na sua questão.